# Entity Framework in ASP.net

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am using a database-first approach for Entity Framework. Below is my table. I have an identity column in my table, but when the `dbcontext` class is created, it has `entity.HasNoKey` in the `OnModelCreating` method.

Below is the automatically generated code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityPersonalData>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasNoKey();

                entity.ToTable("Identity_PersonalData");

                entity.Property(e => e.Address1)
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Address2)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.City)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Email)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.FirstName)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.LastName)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.MiddleName)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.PhoneNumber)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.RecordId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.Property(e => e.RequestType)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.State)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Status)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Zip)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
}
```

When I tried to save the data to the database using the code below, I got this error:

> Unable to track an instance of type 'IdentityPersonalData' because it does not have a primary key. Only entity types with primary keys may be tracked.

```
public void SaveData(IdentityPersonalData objPerson)
{
        using (IdentityProofContext IdContext = new IdentityProofContext())
        {
            IdContext.IdentityPersonalData.Add(objPerson);
            IdContext.SaveChanges();
            Int64 id = objPerson.RecordId;
        }
}
```

This is my class:

```
public partial class IdentityPersonalData
{
        [Key]
        public Int64 RecordId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string RequestType { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

I didn't have a `[Key]` annotation over the `recordId`. I put the key annotation later when I got this error that I  mentioned above. I don't understand why am I getting an error if I already have a key and why the context class was created with `entity.HasNoKey`.

Comment: Most likely you are missing a primary key in the SQL table

Comment: yes, I am missing the primary key

Comment: You have explicitly specified that your model does not have a key: `entity.HasNoKey();`

Comment: I made the primary key. Now what do I need to do so that dbcontext class does not throw that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have explicitly specified that the model has no key at all when you added to the model builder

```
entity.HasNoKey();
```

Remove that and add

```
e.HasKey(s => s.RecordId);
```